# Error when trying to render data conditionally in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, contentful

I am querying data from a CMS via Graphql into my Gatsby project.

Sadly I was not thinking ahead and the content types text field wasn't set to required or given a default value, so now the value of this text field is for some elements `null`.

I tried avoiding this giving me issues by rendering the elements through a conditional statement checking if the element is empty or not.

This is my entire file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image"
import Layout from '../components/Layout'

import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"
import MDXRenderer from "gatsby-plugin-mdx/mdx-renderer"


export default function MalreiTemplate({ data }) {
    const picture = data.allContentfulMalerei.nodes

    return (
        <Layout>
          {picture.map(pic => {
              const image = getImage(pic.image)
              return(
              <div key={pic.slug} className="mb-3">
                <div className="pt-3 d-flex justify-content-between">
                  <span><Link to="/malerei" style={{textDecoration: "none", color: "#589AAD"}}>&#8592; zurück</Link></span>
                </div>
                  <hr />
                <div className="artwork-detail-container d-flex">
                  <div className="artwork-detail-image-container">
                    <GatsbyImage image={image}/>
                  </div>
                  <div className="artwork-detail-text">
                    <h3>{pic.title}, {pic.year}</h3>
                    <h4>{pic.type}</h4>
                    <p className="pt-4">
                      <MDXProvider>
                        <MDXRenderer>
                          {pic.description !== null ? <p>{pic.description}</p> : <p>.</p>}
                        </MDXRenderer>
                      </MDXProvider>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
              </div>
          )})}
        </Layout>
    )
}


export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
      allContentfulMalerei(filter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
        nodes {
          year
          width
          title
          description {
            childMdx {
              body
            }
          }
          image {
            gatsbyImageData(width: 600, placeholder: BLURRED)
          }
        }
      }
    }
`
```

This is the relevant part:

```
<MDXProvider>
  <MDXRenderer>
    {pic.description ? pic.description.childMdx.body : <p>.</p>}
  </MDXRenderer>
</MDXProvider>
```

I am getting this error message in return when I visit pages for those elements that have no text field. On all other sites I can see the content with no error.

Would someone have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would replace:

```
<p className="pt-4">
  <MDXProvider>
    <MDXRenderer>
      {pic.description ? <p>{pic.description.childMdx.body}</p> : <p>.</p>}
    </MDXRenderer>
  </MDXProvider>
</p>
```

with:

```
{ picDescription ? (<p className="pt-4">{pic.description}</p>) : null }
```

because I don't see what value the MDX components are adding there and I suspect that error is coming from MDX (but I don't know for sure).

Comment: Thank you Michel. This does work, with the change of the first statement as so: 
`   { pic.description ? (<p className="pt-4">{pic.description.childMdx.body}</p>) : null }` though, it will only give me code, not text. i somehow need to render it so it shows as text.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add another class to `pt-4` that displays as text. Please check your stylesheet.